# Read key of array two dimension

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-key

I try to read some keys of an array like

> array(3) {
>
> ["poste5:"]=> array(3)  { [0]=> string(7) "APPLE:"  [1]=> string(5)
>   "demo1"  [2]=> string(5) "demo2" }
>
> ["services:"]=> array(4) {  [0]=> string(9) "orange"  [1]=>
>   string(5) "demo3" [2]=> string(5) "demo4"  [3]=> string(5) "demo1" }
>
> ["essai:"]=> array(2) {  [0]=> string(6) "sd" } }

I try to read this name : **poste5** , **services** , **essai**

If i use :

```
foreach ($this->aliasRead as $key => $value){

echo array_keys($this->aliasRead[$key]);
}
```

I have : **Array()**

But if i use :

```
foreach (array_keys($this->aliasRead) as $key => $value2) {
       echo $value2;
}
```

I have **poste5** , **services** , **essai**

I try to use with this loop **foreach ($this->aliasRead as $key => $value){**
because i have another traitment after. 
How to collect this key of my first loop in this loop **foreach ($this->aliasRead as $key => $value){** ?

Comment: I must admit I have problems to understand your question. If you need to collect something you normally store it into a variable in programming. However, I can't see that you make use of a variable here. So I'm a bit puzzled where you hit the roadblock.

Comment: And you have right, i correct that :) but i just want to have some opinion and explication ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have what you want here:

```
foreach ($this->aliasRead as $key => $value){
    echo $key; // key of the value in the array
    print_r($value); // value of $this->aliasRead[$key] which in turn is another array
}
```

Edit: The reason your second loop works is because of this: `array_keys($this->aliasRead[$key])` returns a new array containing the keys of the old array as its values. So `$myNewArray = array_keys($this->aliasRead[$key])` is the same as `$myNewArray = array('poste5','services','essai')`. So, when you loop over this new array like this:

```
foreach ($myNewArray as $key => $value2) {
    echo $value2;
}
```

`$value2` contains your values, which are the keys of your first array, and `$key` will be 0, 1 and 2 after each step through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$keys = array_keys($this->aliasRead);
print_r($keys);
```

Or

```
$keys = array();
foreach ($this->aliasRead as $key => $value){
 $keys[] = $key;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're trying to `echo` an array. This will always give you the string "Array". If you want to see the array's contents, try

```
var_dump(array_keys($this->aliasRead[$key]));
```

By the way, in the `foreach` statement you posted, `$this->aliasRead[$key]` will be the equal to `$value`. So this will work as well:

```
var_dump(array_keys($value));
```